# How to stop client side rendering in Gridsome?

Tags: vue.js, rendering, server-side-rendering, gridsome

The data on my page is re-generated on Gridsome Vue component render in the browser which is already pre-generated in SSR.

How to stop and stop client-side Vue component rendering?

Comment: gridsome builds a static site from your sources. Are you trying to stop loading the SPA in the background?

Comment: @kasvith ...that's not entirely correct. Gridsome builds static HTML yes, but Vue is still there a takes over rendering after all JS is loaded...

Comment: Yes, Vue is used there as a SPA, so once you loaded a page, it will load the rest in the background. It's not pure HTML like in hugo.

Comment: Actually, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it on per-component basis.

But you can opt-out of Vue by not loading any JS generated for your app by [overriding default `Index.html`](https://gridsome.org/docs/overriding-index/) which will of course disable **any** Vue functionality on client side

Here is a sample `index.html` template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ${htmlAttrs}>
  <head>
    ${title}
    ${base}
    ${hash}
    ${vueMetaTags}
    ${vueMetaLinks}
    ${styles}
    ${vueMetaStyles}
    ${vueMetaScripts}
  </head>
  <body ${bodyAttrs}>
    ${app}
  </body>
</html>
```

Credit to DerAlbertCom - see [this issue](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/1000)